# Please use a storage account managed by Storage Resource Provider. Use of storage account is not supported

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage

I am using JSON template to create VM using Azure Images.  I am continuously getting error while deplying as "Please use a storage account managed by Storage Resource Provider. Use of portalvhdslzdvpym2x33f5 (storage account) is not supported.  Can please anyone help me in solving this.  I am providing three paramaters :

```
"userImageStorageAccountName": {
   "type": "string"
},
"userImageStorageContainerName": {
   "type": "string"
},
"userImageVhdName": {
   "type": "string"
},
```

Comment: How was the account you're using created?

Comment: it was created by default in Azure.

Comment: There's two types of storage accounts. Is this classic (an older account) or created with the new portal? One way of telling this would be to check if the account is in a resource group (then it's a newer account) vs not in a resource group (classic account).

Comment: ok. You say that if I use storage account listed  in New Azure Portal then I can overcome this issue. Let me try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Emily is correct that there are two types of storage accounts - the classic (original) accounts created by the old portal - and the newer accounts managed by the new portal. In the new portal you can see storage accounts sorted either by Storage Accounts (Classic) or Storage Accounts. If your account appears under the classic category you can't interact with it via SRP.